# predict "conflicts" with own revisions?

Tags: svn

I've checked out multiple copies of a particular "library" from my SVN repository -- one copy for each of my work-related projects that use the same code. I've made modifications in one that I've committed to the repository, and I would like to update the copies in the rest of my projects to reflect these changes.

However, I would like to reserve the right to reject a small number of changes for one of my ongoing projects, so it would be great if there was some way I can get a warning for conflicts with files [named as](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch03s05.html) `filename.mine`, `filename.rOLDREV`, and `filename.rNEWREV` as if another user had committed these changes (but these changes have already been committed to the repository by me), rather than automatically updating all affected files (with `svn update`).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use branches instead of checkouting the same project multiple times.

imagine this repos:

```
repos
  |-- trunk/
  |-- branches/
        |-- projectX
        |-- projectY
        `-- projectZ
```

Let's say you develop a feature, and wanted to add it in the projectY only, you could the [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html) the code from trunk to `branches/projectY`.

If another feature was to be include in the `projectX` and `projectZ`, you the merge the feature to those two branches.

That way, you control what goes in each projects, and the history follow in each projects.

Comment: I like this idea. I will probably do this in the future, but is there a way to retroactively see what the updates will be before committing to the update with `svn update`? Thanks...

Comment: @crippledlambda Not sure what you mean. Do you wish to know how to know what the changes will be before a commit after a merge. OR see what are the changes to the repository server before updating a working copy.

Comment: @yvoyer: I was hoping to do an "update" but have the changed files named filename.mine, filename.rVERSIONNUMBER, etc. I just copied the updated library (SVN project) to a separate branch and tried to merge it with my working library, but it just updated without giving the option of evaluating the changes (through the filename.mine mechanism)...

Comment: @crippledlambda, when merging, you can pass the parameter `--dry-run` to see what files will be affected by the merge, without actually modifying the working copy files. ie. `svn merge -r22:head --dry-run SOURCE_URL .` would tell you the changes made from revision 23 to head. If you execute the same command without the `--dry-run`, the working copy files would be merged. It is used to see if there would be conflict on your working copy, after a merge.

Comment: @crippledlambda, usually `.rVERSIONNUMBER, .mine` files are generated by a conflict, but I don't know how to do it like you want.

Comment: I see... looks like dry-run is what I may have to go for. Thanks for the tip ~

Answer (score 1):

If you have a project A that needs to stay at an old revision of a dependency B, then you can set up a [`svn:externals` property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) in project A which points to B with an explicit revision number. For example, the trunk folder of project A would have a `svn:externals` property with this content:

```
-r148 http://svn.example.com/projects/B/trunk B
```

When you checkout project A, this will cause a folder `B` to appear containing revision 148 of the trunk of project B. Changes to project B will not affect A until you explicitly change the revision number in the `svn:externals` property.

Comment: Very interesting ... and complicated (not really), but I may try this out... Thanks! Will report back soon.

Comment: This is great, but guess I have to know which conflicts I want to resolve a priori -- but possibly useful later. Thanks!